# React native SetState array every half second Make App hang with large data

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, state

I am working on Trading application using React Native where data needs to get update every 0.5 second interval.

I am using **setState** to update the latest array in parent component and passing values in child component to bind list values.

It makes app hang while array item become more than 100 items while make SetState in comment working fine but no update values in DOM.

Can I use ForceUpdate to Update values in DOM or any Other solution please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attach code for proper understanding, maybe your iteration is not correct

Comment: Added Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

use flatList for mapping large list

Flatlist is cool because it does the rendering for you and renders the items as they are needed on the screen instead of all at once which is the case of the ScrollView. You provide the FlatList an array of data and what the items should look like and it runs it through it's own mapping function.

here is link to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: Using FlatList Only but App hang after setState every half second with large data

Comment: use pagination with flat list

Comment: We can not use it as per requirement of application. is there is work around for state issue or can state create issue with large data in interval?

Comment: Can remove State and use ForceUpdate to update DOM?